# Least Squares estimator of $\beta$ using matrices

Tags: regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Show, using matrix notation and staring with the principle of least squares, that the least squares estimator of $\beta$ is given by:

$\hat\beta =$ $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2}$

I'm not even sure how to start this problem. Would anyone be willing to help me start to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The OLS in matrix notations is 
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty,
$$
where the design matris is $n\times 1$ matrix of the following form
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and 
$$
y=\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence 
$$
X^TX = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 \to(X^TX)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2},
$$
and 
$$
X^Ty=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i,
$$
thus 
$$
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}.
$$